# Keep value for each datetime group

Tags: python, pandas

```
                     A  B    C    D
0  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  110  3.9
1  2002-01-13 15:00:00  Y  120  1.9
2  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  130  8.0 
3  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  140  9.0
4  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  110  0.2
5  2002-01-14 16:00:00  Y  120  7.0
6  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  130  1.6
7  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  140  3.4
```

I want to create a new column `df["E"]` that takes *D value* when *B = Y*, and keep this value for each *A group*.

Output should be:

```
                     A  B    C    D     E
0  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  110  3.9   1.9
1  2002-01-13 15:00:00  Y  120  1.9   1.9
2  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  130  8.0   1.9
3  2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  140  9.0   1.9
4  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  110  0.2   7.0
5  2002-01-14 16:00:00  Y  120  7.0   7.0
6  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  130  1.6   7.0
7  2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  140  3.4   7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [8]: df.merge(df.loc[df.B=='Y', ['A', 'D']].rename(columns={'D':'E'}))
Out[8]:
                    A  B    C    D    E
0 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  110  3.9  1.9
1 2002-01-13 15:00:00  Y  120  1.9  1.9
2 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  130  8.0  1.9
3 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  140  9.0  1.9
4 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  110  0.2  7.0
5 2002-01-14 16:00:00  Y  120  7.0  7.0
6 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  130  1.6  7.0
7 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  140  3.4  7.0
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [35]: df['E'] = df['A'].map(df.loc[df.B=='Y', ['A', 'D']].set_index('A')['D'])

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
                    A  B    C    D    E
0 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  110  3.9  1.9
1 2002-01-13 15:00:00  Y  120  1.9  1.9
2 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  130  8.0  1.9
3 2002-01-13 15:00:00  X  140  9.0  1.9
4 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  110  0.2  7.0
5 2002-01-14 16:00:00  Y  120  7.0  7.0
6 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  130  1.6  7.0
7 2002-01-14 16:00:00  X  140  3.4  7.0
```